# M2M association not loading the fields on the passthrough table [Sequelize]

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, eager-loading

I've been having an issue on sequelize where I have 3 different models:

```
const School = sequelize.define('school', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
    description: Sequelize.STRING,
    private: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
    updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE
})

const SchoolMember = sequelize.define('schoolMember', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    isAdmin: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    schoolId: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: 'communities',
            key: 'id'
        }
    },
    profileId: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: 'profiles',
            key: 'id'
        }
    },
    createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
    updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE,
})

const Profile = sequelize.define('profile', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
    description: Sequelize.STRING,
    picture: Sequelize.STRING,
    createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
    updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE
})
```

I have made a many to many association between School and Profile using SchoolMember as the passthrough table like this:

```
School.belongsToMany(Profile, {
        through: 'schoolMembers',
        as: 'members'
    })
```

Now, when I try to fetch my school on my API:

```
const school = await School.findOne({
        where: {
            id: schoolId
        },
        include: {
            all: true,
            nested: true
        }
    })
```

I receive my object with an extra field called members

```
members: Array(1)
0:
agreement: true
schoolMembers:
schoolId: 1
createdAt: "2021-07-26T18:13:00.210Z"
profileId: 1
updatedAt: "2021-07-26T18:13:00.210Z"
__proto__: Object


...
//Profile data...
...
```

but It's not loading neither the ID or the isAdmin value (which I really need)
What am I missing here?
Thanks for the help